# SSRS Lookup and Join Function

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, lookup

I am trying to display values in a list depending on the values passed in from a parameter. I have the following code in the expression builder:

```
=Join(Lookup(Parameters!department.Value, Fields!department_id.Value, Fields!NAME.Value, "departments"), ", ")
```

Which is included as an expression: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AJ70.png).

When I run the report, however, it simply shows: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzQDm.png).

I've been looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-ver15

Not sure why it isn't working. It works when I do not include the lookup part of the function.

```
=Join(Parameters!department.Value, ", ")
```

Comment: Have you run the report from the Visual Studio Preview? It uses gives a somewhat vague error message that might give a better idea of the issue than the #ERROR.

Comment: Assuming the names are actually in the parameter's label property could you simply do `=Join(Parameters!department.Label, ", ")`

Comment: I'll add this as an answer so yo can accept it, otherwise the question will still show as not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the names are actually in the parameter's label property could you simply do

```
=Join(Parameters!department.Label, ", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alan Schofield. It does have a label property, that worked perfectly.

```
=Join(Parameters!department.Label, ", ")
```